# 自分で定義したrakeタスクの一覧を表示する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

自分で定義したタスクは `lib/tasks/*.rake`の形で置いているのですが、ここで定義されているrake のタスク一覧を表示する方法はありますか？

rakeタスク全体であれば `rake -T`ということはわかったのですが、個別定義したもののみ抜き出したい時にどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分で定義したタスクはネームスペースを使用すると、[タスクをネームスペースによってフィルタする](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16106592/1167750)ことが出来ると思います。

例えば、もし`example.rake`というタスクがあれば：

```
# lib/tasks/example.rake
namespace :example do
  task :example_task do
    puts "自分で定義したタスクです"
  end
end
```

フィルタ・コマンドはこうなります：

```
rake -T example -A
```

コマンドの実行結果は：

```
rake example:example_task  #
```

---

追記：`rake >= 10.5.0`の場合は、`rake -A`のオプションを使うのは全部のタスクを表示するためなんですが、`rake -T`のコマンドを使うと、記述のないタスクは表示されないと思います。

Comment: 事前に namespaceをわけておく必要があるんですね。ありがとうございます。